# What is the difference between spring 2.5 and spring 3.x?

Tags: spring

I have been working on spring 2.5, I just wanted to know the difference between spring 2.5 and spring 3.x. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One place would be the spring documentation, specifically [what is new in spring 3.0](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-whats-new.html)